# How to put conditions on a search engine, built on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A CodeIgniter application has a search engine, and I want to add conditions to the results.
Some of the code that are in the Models:

```
$this->db->select(users.country_symbol);
```

and

```
function getUsers($conditions=array())
{
    //Check For Conditions
    if (is_array($conditions) and count($conditions)>0)     
        $this->db->where($conditions); 
}
```

On The controller I have:

```
$users = $this->search_model->getUsers(NULL)
```

How can I change NULL into a condition that request for users with the same country_symbol as the `$this->loggedInUser->country_symbol`?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function like this:

```
function getUsers($conditions = array())
{
    if (is_array($conditions) && count($conditions) > 0) {
        foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
            $this->db->where($condition['where'], $condition['value']);
        }
    }

    // return results...
}
```

And then you could do this:

```
$conditions = array(
    array('where' => 'country_symbol =', 'value' => $this->loggedInUser->country_symbol),
    array('where' => 'zip_code', 'value' => '12345'),
    // and so on...
)

$users = $this->search_model->getUsers($conditions);
```

I haven't tested this code but that's the basic idea.  You'll need to loop through the conditions array and apply each condition with `$this->db->where()` or a similar function.